# Matrix For Arrival Process of Data Packets for Different Time Slots in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector

I want to define a matrix (ag,t) that can take the values of an arrival process that follows Binomial Distribution. Its values should be different for each timeslot. I am not sure how to follow the problem and would really appreciate help in this regards. The attached picture explains the query.

[image: Requirement]

This is what I have tried but I don't know how to define it such that it different for each time slot.

```
cluster_nbrs = 3;
G = zeros(1,cluster_nbrs);
p = 0.97; % Probability of packet being transferred
n = 1000; % # of time slots
arrival_gt = zeros(1,cluster_nbrs); % Arrival Process during slot t  
for q = 1:cluster_nbrs
    % Probability that arrival = n
    arrival_gt(q) = binopdf(G(q),n,p); 
end
```

Comment: How have you attempted to solve the problem so far?

Comment: @mikkola `t = 1000;                                                                   % # of time slots at which packet is transferred
arrival_gt = zeros(1,cluster_nbrs);                                         % Arrival Process of a given data packet during time slot t
for q = 1:cluster_nbrs
   arrival_gt (q) = binopdf(G(q),1000,p);                                   % Probability that arrival = n
end`

Comment: You can edit that into the question itself. And it is not very helpful without an actual question...

Comment: @mikkola editted.